# replacing string from array

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I have an array

```
$cop_row = array('first_pulse1', 'second_pulse2');
```

what I want is to replace **first_**  & **second_** from the **cop_row** array .

I am using this right now but it is not giving me the required result.

```
str_replace("first_","",$cop_row);
```

I am getting output

```
pulse1second_pulse2
```

What I want is

```
pulse1pulse2
```

Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will solve your problem.

```
php > $x = ['first_pulse', 'second_pulse'];
php > $q = preg_replace('/(\w+)_/i', '', $x);
php > print_r($q);
Array
(
    [0] => pulse
    [1] => pulse
)
php >
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 2):

If the strings are always formatted like this, then you could use this basic RegExp replacement:

```
preg_replace("/^.*_/", "", $cop_row)
```

The pattern might need some improvements, but it works for your cases.

If you need further assistance or explanation regarding the pattern, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 2):

```
$cop_row = array('first_pulse1', 'second_pulse2');

foreach ($cop_row as $key => $value) {
    $result_array[] = substr($value, strpos($value, "_") + 1);  
}

print_r($result_array);
```

Working example here - http://codepad.org/nOqWdmNu

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$cop_row = array('first_pulse1', 'second_pulse2');

$patterns[0] = '/first_/';
$patterns[1] = '/second_/';
foreach($cop_row as $row){
    echo preg_replace($patterns, '', $row); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $replace = ["first_","second_"];
 $cop_row = array('first_pulse1', 'second_pulse2');
 str_replace($replace,"",$cop_row);
```

Please have a look into https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp